# [].slice.call(arguments) не копирует значение в массив

Tags: javascript

Имеется простой пример работы функции логирования:

```
function work(a) {
  /* ... */ // work - произвольная функция
}
function makeLogging(f, log) { 
    return function(){
        log.push(arguments[0]);
        f.apply(this,arguments);
    }
}
var log = [];
work = makeLogging(work, log);
work(1); // 1, добавлено в log
work(5); // 5, добавлено в log
for (var i = 0; i < log.length; i++) {
  alert( 'Лог:' + log[i] ); // "Лог:1", затем "Лог:5"
}
```

При таком коде все успешно работает, согласно комментариям. Изначально, я попробовал иначе:

```
function makeLogging(f, log) { 
    return function(){
        log=[].slice.call(arguments);// изменения тут
        f.apply(this,arguments);
    }
}
```

По понятным причинам это не сработало так, как планировалось по заданию, но я ожидал от данного кода, что массив `log` всегда будет иметь значение аргумента последней вызванной функции, однако, если после вызова `work(1)` посмотреть содержимое `log`, он окажется пустым. Я не до конца понимаю почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из-за того, что **локальной** переменной **присваивается** новое значение, никакого отображения на глобальной переменной нет.

Проблема скорее в неверном именовании, если немного переименовать, станет понятнее:

```
var log = [];
function makeLogging(f, logArr) { 
    return function(){
        logArr=[].slice.call(arguments);// изменения тут
        f.apply(this,arguments);
    }
}
```

Теперь видно, что изменения происходят именно с локальной переменной, а не глобальной, значение которой проверяется после выполнения функции.

Для решения достаточно менять не всю ссылку, а один элемент, либо делать `push`/`shift`, которые меняют сам переданный массив.

Например:

```js
function work(a) {
  console.log('work', a);
}

function makeLogging(f, log) {
  return function() {
    log[0] = [].slice.call(arguments); // изменения тут
    f.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}

var log = [];
work = makeLogging(work, log);
work(1); // 1, добавлено в log
console.log(log)
```

Comment: Но ведь в функцию я передаю ссылку на глобальный объект, правильно ли я понимаю, что используя мой 2й вариант, я "перетираю" свою ссылку, теряя контекст?

Comment: Не очень понятно, что из себя представляет переданный массив в качестве аргумента в функцию. Я думал, что это ссылка на область памяти, она статична и , если я выполняю присваивание, то ссылка остается, прежней, меняется лишь значение в ячейках памяти, на которую данная ссылка указывает. А так получается, что при присваивании, я как будто новую локальную переменную создал

Comment: @Kayrosik, _правильно ли я понимаю, что используя мой 2й вариант, я "перетираю" свою ссылку, теряя контекст?_ - да, после присваивания **локальная** переменная начинает ссылаться на новый массив, который вернул `slice`, если выведешь его внутри функции - увидишь что все в порядке.

Comment: @Kayrosik, в качестве аргумента передается ссылка на массив, значит значение параметра - ссылка, если ты присвоил параметру другое значение - первоначальная ссылка никак не меняется.

Comment: @Grundy @Kayrosik - Надо `log[0]=[].slice.call(arguments);` переделать в `[].push.apply(log, [].slice.call(arguments));` и все будет ОК

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, тогда уж `log.push(...arguments)` но скорее всего нужен как массив элементов: `log.push([...arguments])`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, стало понятнее. А если мне нужно передать в функцию 2 массива в качестве аргументов, чтобы внутри первому присвоить второй с соответствующими изменениями в глобальной области видимости (пример странный, но поможет мне немного с пониманием), как в таком случае сделать?

Comment: @Kayrosik, так по описанию не совсем понятно, что именно ты имеешь ввиду, можешь либо отредактировать текущий вопрос, добавив пример кода и ожидаемый результат либо задать новый вопрос